# Cakephp 3.6 Search Get find

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I've been trying to use this code to retrive data from a table
but it doesnt seem to work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

default.ctp

```
<div class="title_right">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>

 <?= $this->Form->create("",['type'=>'get']) ?>
 <?= $this->Form->control('search', ['default'=>$this->request->query('search')]); ?>
 <?= $this->Form->end() ?>``
```

UsersController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $search = $this->request->query('search');
    if(!empty($search)){
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' =>['Users LIKE '=>'%'.$search. '%']

        ];
    }
```

How to insert the form search inside the button?

Comment: You shouldnt use such a non standard approach IMO, Use proper PRG pattern as outlined in the existing de facto standard for filtering as plugin: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/

Comment: You have to specify the name of the field you want to search against. i.e. `Users.username LIKE ....`. But also consider following mark suggestion

Comment: about the button: simply put it somewhere between form->create() and form->end(). But I suggest using FormHelper instead of pure html

Comment: Its already complicated as it is for me I rather use it this way 
It work Im just having trouble with the Search button "Go" isn't working

Comment: As I tried to explain: There wouldnt be any trouble using what everyone else is using :) It is also more user friendly for the people using your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed change made

```
$search = $this->request->query('search');
    if(!empty($search)){
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' =>['Users.full_name LIKE '=>'%'.$search. '%']

        ];
    }else{

    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 4 );
      [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'SourceProspects', 'Status']
    ];
  }
    $prospects = $this->paginate($this->Users);

    $this->set(compact('prospects'));
    $this->set('title', 'Manage Prospect');
    $this->set('user_session', $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User'));
}
```

As for the button

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 form-group top_search">
              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <?= $this->Form->create("",['type'=>'get']) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->control('search', ['default'=>$this->request->getQuery('search'),'class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Search For Name'
                  ]); ?>
                    <button class="btn btn-default ">Go!</button>
                    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
                </span>
                </div>
                </div>
```